# Understanding genesis_markup() in Genesis Framework

Tags: wordpress, genesis

I don't understand how the genesis_markup function turns:

```
array(
    'open'  => '<aside class="widget-areainfo-onder-content">',
    'context' => 'widget-area-wrap',
    'echo'    => false,
    'params'  => array(
      'id'  => $id,
    )
```

into

```
"<div class="widget-area">"
```

I do not understand why the id is not used in the output at all and the aside class is also not used....I would have thought that it should be.....

When I do this in the code:

```
$before_markup_args = array(
    'open'  => '<aside class="widget-areainfo-onder-content">',
    'context' => 'widget-area-wrap',
    'echo'    => false,
    'params'  => array(
      'id'  => $id,
    )
  );

  d($before_markup_args);

  d(genesis_markup( $before_markup_args ));
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I would like to confirm the missing space:

````
    ```
    $before_markup_args = array(
        'open'  => '<aside class="widget-area info-onder-content">',
        'context' => 'widget-area-wrap',
        'echo'    => false,
        'params'  => array(
           'id'  => $id,
        )
       );
       ```
````

"Onder" is Dutch for "Below". Thus, "info-onder-content" means "info-below-content". Possibly a title for the widget area.

This is a code example that is used for the genesis_widget_area function, typically found in a functions.php file in a WordPress Genesis child theme.

```
$widget_area_args = array('before' => genesis_markup($before_markup_args),
        );
genesis_widget_area($id, $widget_area_args);
```

We can understand how this works by looking up the definition of the genesis_widget_area function in the /var/www/html/wp-content/themes/genesis/lib/functions/widgetize.php file.

```
function genesis_widget_area( $id, $args = array() ) {

    if ( ! $id ) {
        return false;
    }

    $defaults = apply_filters(
        'genesis_widget_area_defaults',
        array(
            'before'              => genesis_markup(
                array(
                    'open'    => '<aside class="widget-area">' . genesis_sidebar_title( $id ),
                    'context' => 'widget-area-wrap',
                    'echo'    => false,
                    'params'  => array(
                        'id' => $id,
                    ),
                )
            ),
            'after'               => genesis_markup(
                array(
                    'close'   => '</aside>',
                    'context' => 'widget-area-wrap',
                    'echo'    => false,
                )
            ),
            'default'             => '',
            'show_inactive'       => 0,
            'before_sidebar_hook' => 'genesis_before_' . $id . '_widget_area',
            'after_sidebar_hook'  => 'genesis_after_' . $id . '_widget_area',
        ),
        $id,
        $args
    );

    $args = wp_parse_args( $args, $defaults );

    if ( ! $args['show_inactive'] && ! is_active_sidebar( $id ) ) {
        return false;
    }
```